# How to get the span text from a checkbox using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, checkbox, text

Suppose I have the following bit of code:

```
  <p>
    <label>
      <input name="milk" type="checkbox">
      <span>Milk</span>
    </label>
  </p>
```

How can I use javascript to obtain the text between the `span` tags? The result should be `Milk` if logged onto the console. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send `this` into the onclick method of your checkbox, so the function it is calling can keep track of the element that was clicked and also access it's parent in order to access the parent's child span element.

See below:

```js
function printText(el) {
  console.log( el.parentNode.querySelector('span').innerHTML );
}
```

```html
<p>
  <label>
    <input name="milk" type="checkbox" onclick="printText(this)">
    <span>Milk</span>
  </label>
</p>
```

---

**Edit:** OP asks what if HTML can't be changed

If altering the HTML is not an option you can then find the checkbox and span elements through javascript like this:

```js
var chkBox = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"][name="milk"]');

chkBox.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if(this.checked) { // remove this if statement if you want it to print on every click
    console.log( this.parentNode.querySelector('span').innerHTML );
  }
});
```

```html
<p>
  <label>
    <input name="milk" type="checkbox">
    <span>Milk</span>
  </label>
</p>
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your message! But what if the html can't be changed?

Comment: @peachpops Ok, I edited my answer to include your scenario. Let me know if that fixes your problem

Comment: @peachpops No problem, take care